# How to read data from a csv file in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, forms, admin-panel

I have created a admin template page in magento. ON this page I created a form to browse a csv file and on click submit button I want to send this via ajax to a controller action and there I want to get csv data and insert into custom table.

Below is my code :

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<button name="submit" id="import_button" value="" type="submit" onclick="importData()" >Submit</button>
```

and ajax is here :

```
function importData()
{
    var file = jQuery('input[type=file]').prop("files")[0];
        ajaxBlockUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*\/*\/import') ?>';
        new Ajax.Request(ajaxBlockUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            parameters: {isAjax: 'true', form_key: FORM_KEY, file : file},
            onSuccess: function (response)
            {
                // success
            }
        });

}
```

and my controller action :

```
// how to I get file here
$_FILES['file']['name'];
$file = $this->getRequest()->getParam('file');
```

My ajax calls successfully controller action but How do I get file here and read data from it?

Comment: you can not submit file in normal ajax call

Comment: Please post an alternative, How will do this ?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari working on admin-end or frontend?

Comment: use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to send input type file using ajax

Comment: @QaisarSatti, I amworking on admin page, I have created a menu in admin  and in controller indexAction load template file there.

Comment: @MineshPatel, Can you please tell me How to use `FormData` with my code?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari i posted the code that i am using for import csv..

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari added my answer.try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your form phtml

```
<div class="content-header">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="grid-header">
        <tr>
            <td><h3><?php echo $this->__('Import Tracking Number')?></h3></td>
            <td class="a-right">
                <button onclick="editForm.submit()" class="scalable save" type="button"><span>Import</span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="entry-edit">
    <form id="edit_form" name="edit_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/import')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
        <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend"><?php echo $this->__('Import CSV File ')?></h4>
        </div>
        <fieldset id="my-fieldset">
            <table cellspacing="0" class="form-list">
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Add CSV File to Import')?> <span class="required">*</span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><input type="file" class="input-text required-entry" name="csv" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editForm = new varienForm('edit_form');
</script>
```

Controller code

```
 public function importAction()
  {

      $File=$_FILES['csv']['name'];
      $_FILES['csv']['type'];
     $mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','application/octet-stream','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
     if(in_array($_FILES['csv']['type'],$mimes)){
       $absolute_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .('massorderprocessing');
 $relative_path = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        // File Upload
        $files = $_FILES['csv']['name'];

                  if(file_exists($absolute_path.DS.$files))
                 {
                       $var = rand(0,99);
                       $files = $var.'_'.$files;
                  }
                  $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('csv');
                  $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                 $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                   $uploader->save($absolute_path, $files);

      $csvObject = new Varien_File_Csv();
      $data=$csvObject->getData($absolute_path.'/'.$files);

      foreach($data as $dat)
      {
           //do your logic here
      }

  }
```

Comment: Trying your code, will let you know if it work.

Comment: This code uploaded file successfully, but unable to read data from CSV. If my column name is `Import Area` then How to read its value in loop?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari that depend on your csv file `$dat[0]` for first column value `$dat[2]` for second and goes on.

Comment: When I log `$data` into log file it return me unreadable data like `PK!A7‚Ïr[Content_Types].xml ¢( ¬”ËnÂ0E÷•ú‘·Ubè¢ª*‹>–-ôL<$Žmy`.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari you are adding the xml file? this is for csv

Comment: No, I am adding CSV file. But my file has empty rows.

Comment: I tried with another file and now getting the result, Thank you for your post.

Comment: $dat[0] gives me rows value like 'column1 column2', 'column1 column2' etc. How to get columns value in loop?

Comment: you added comma separated values? `value1,value2,value3` like these

Comment: No I have two column, and $dat[0] in loop gives me result firstrow -> 'col1 col2', secondrow -> 'col1 col2'.etc.

Comment: comma represent the column not space so do `firstrow -> 'col1','col2'` break line then add new line 
`secondrow -> 'col1','col2'`

Answer (score 0):

Try below and let me know if it works. i have not checked code

```
function importData()
{
    var file = jQuery('input[type=file]').prop("files")[0];
    var formData = new FormData(file);
    formData.append("isAjax", true);
    formData.append("form_key", FORM_KEY);
        ajaxBlockUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*\/*\/import') ?>';
        new Ajax.Request(ajaxBlockUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            parameters: {formData},
            onSuccess: function (response)
            {
                // success
            }
        });

}
```