# CSV file upload

Tags: magento2, csv, file-upload

Can anybody help me with how to upload the CSV file from the frontend of magento2?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148967/how-to-read-data-from-a-csv-file-in-magento

Comment: The above link is the answer to my question.

Comment: Not exactly....but what I want I found there. like uploading a CSV file.

Comment: if you have the exact answer. Then please do answer it.